# Module Not Found Error while trying to run Hello World program in node.js [Resolved]

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tried executing myfirst.js program from the terminal (Directory/command mentioned below). I was expecting a run window or a browser popup.

Typed `node myfirst.js` in the terminal while being in the same directory. The error I get:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\{UserName}\myfirst.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.11.1
```

Exact directory\command: `C:\Users\{UserName}>node myfirst.js`

Path where node is installed: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Path of file: `C:\Users\{UserName}\myfirst.js`

Any help would be appreciated.

Issue Detected: myfirst.js wasn`t saved as a js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that the file is not saved as a text file (`.txt`), such that it would actually be `myfirst.js.txt`. Node can parse text files, so running `node myfirst.js.txt` would work in that case. This also applies to files that don't have an extension, as in `myfirst` instead of `myfirst.js`.

I would recommend using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as an environment, as it has [syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xziN8.png) and a [built in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpdkJ.png), which can be invaluable for learning to code.

Comment: Thank you for your help and comment, much thanks. I downloaded Visual Studio Code after some time. I have noted to be careful while saving files.